# Basement foundation bowing inward and cracks

Tags: basement

Foundation Walls are bowing inward in basement and big cracks and step cracks should I leave my house ? Is it safe ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Is this a change? If so, how fast has it been changing? (And, in any case we aren't going to be able to guarantee your safety...)

Comment: A few pictures would help.

Comment: Concrete , cinder block , stone , or ? . As noted , what is the timing ? I have seen bowed concrete that was stable for many years.

Answer (score 0):

If anything has happened recently like rain, snow melting, earthquake, construction nearby, construction at your house etc. Get out and have someone licensed by whatever governing body in your area is look at it asap. If you notice the wall move or crack yourself get out and call emergency services. If it's just always been like that and some cracks are developing have it looked at asap and if you feel better get out. Pictures would help.